# Docker Error: container id followed by "command not found"

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash, docker

I'm having difficulty with a script I'm writing. The script is largely incomplete, but so far I expect it to be able to run containers successfully. When I execute the script I'm given an error with a container ID and "command not found". For example: `./wordpress: line 73: 3c0fba4984f3b70f0eb3f1c15a7b157f4862b9b243657a3d2f7141029fb6641a: command not found`

The script I'm using is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Setting Constants"
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
MYSQL_DATABASE='wordpress'
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD='password'
WP_PORT='80'
DB_PORT='3306'

EPOCH=$(date +%s)    # append EPOCH to container names for uniqueness
#FILE='blogcontainers'  # filename containing container IDs

DB_CONTAINER_NAME="myblogdb$EPOCH"
WP_CONTAINER_NAME="myblog$EPOCH"

DB_IMG_NAME='blogdb'            # MySQL Docker image
WP_IMG_NAME='blog'          # WordPress Docker image

cd ~/myblog
WP_CID_FILE="$PWD/blog.cid"
DB_CID_FILE="$PWD/blogdb.cid"

if [ -f $DB_CID_FILE ]; then
    DB_IMG_ID=$(sed -n '1p' $DB_CID_FILE) 
else
        echo "dbcid not found"
    # set to baseline image
    DB_IMG_ID="f09a5b2903dc"        
fi

if [ -f $WP_CID_FILE ]; then
    WP_IMG_ID=$(sed -n '1p' $WP_CID_FILE)  
else
    echo "wpcid not found"
    # set to baseline image
    WP_IMG_ID="a8d48bc2313d"
fi

DB_PATH='/var/lib/mysql'         # standard MySQL path
WP_PATH='/var/www/html'          # standard WordPress path
LOCAL_DB_PATH="/$PWD$DB_PATH"
LOCAL_WP_PATH="/$PWD$WP_PATH"


echo "Starting MySQL Container"
#DB_ID=
$(docker run \
     -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD \
     -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE \
     -v $LOCAL_WP_PATH:$DB_PATH \
     -v /$PWD/.bash_history:$WP_PATH \
     --name $DB_CONTAINER_NAME \
     -p $DB_PORT:3306 \
     --cidfile $DB_CID_FILE \
     -d \
     $DB_IMG_ID)



echo "Starting WordPress Container"
#WP_ID=
$(docker run \
     -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD \
     --link $DB_CONTAINER_NAME:$DB_IMG_NAME \
     -p $WP_PORT:80 \
     -v $LOCAL_WP_PATH:$WP_PATH \
     -v /$PWD/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history \
     --name $WP_CONTAINER_NAME \
     --cidfile $WP_CID_FILE \
     -d \
     $WP_IMG_ID)

echo $WP_CONTAINER_NAME
echo $WP_IMG_ID

echo "reached end"

#echo $WP_ID > $FILE                 # copy WordPress container ID to file
#echo $DB_ID >> $FILE                # append MySQL container ID to file
```

After executing the code there usually is a MySQL container instance running. For example:

```
    $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4f2e9ab14c2e        f09a5b2903dc        "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   myblogdb1449768739
```

Also, both **blog.cid** and **blogdb.cid** are created successfully containing container IDs.

```
$ cat blog.cid
e6005bcb4dba524b121d02b301fbe421d67d60986c55d554a0e20443df27ed18
$ cat blogdb.cid
4f2e9ab14c2ea5361557a3714477d7758c993af3b08bbc7db529282a41f90959
```

I've been troubleshooting and searching around for answers, but I think it's time to have another set of eyes take a look at it. As always, any input/criticism are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$(docker run ...)` instead of simply `docker run ...`. The command substitution (`$(...)`) runs the command, captures the output, and expands to that output. As a result, you are trying to run the output of `docker run` as a command.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I was originally writing the output to file, but then I discovered the --cidfile switch.